# listview itemtemplate binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I wrote something like this

```
<ListView Background="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Foos},Path=FooList}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Background="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ComboBox.Items>
                                <sys:String>First</sys:String>
                                <sys:String>Second</sys:String>
                                <sys:String>Third</sys:String>
                                <sys:String>Fourth</sys:String>
                            </ComboBox.Items>
                            <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
                                <Binding Converter="{StaticResource FooTypeToStringConverter}"/> <-- this causes an error -->
                            </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Where Foos

```
<local:Foos x:Key="Foos"/>
```

And behind code from class Foos, where FooList is

```
static BindingList<Foo> fooList = new BindingList<Foo>();
 public static BindingList<Foo> FooList
    {
        get
        {
            return new BindingList<Foo>(fooList.Where //or this is a problem
                (foo =>

                (
                (foo.Name.ToLower()+" "+foo.Number.ToString().ToLower()).Contains(filter)
                || foo.Property2.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || foo.Property3.ToString().ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || foo.Property4.ToString().ToLower().Contains(filter)
                )

                ).ToList());
        }
        set
        {
            fooList = value;
            OnStaticPropertyChanged("FooList");
        }
    }
```

In this moment, converter FooTypeToStringConverter looks like this:

```
public class FooTypeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { MessageBox.Show(value.GetType().ToString()); }));
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

so it's not the reason IMO.

I think I did something stupid, but I don't know - what. Could You help me?

```
<Binding Converter="{StaticResource FooTypeToStringConverter}"/> <-- this causes an error -->
```

Shouldn't I receive an item of FooList (item of type Foo)?

Edit:
Declaration from Window.Resources

```
<FooControl.Resources>
<local:FooTypeToStringConverter x:Key="FooTypeToStringConverter"/>
</FooControl.Resources>
```

And Exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Operacja podawania wartości elementu „System.Windows.Data.Binding” wywołała wyjątek., numer wiersza 47, pozycja 46.

BTW I cannot get the stacktrace, because VS is getting crushed while debuggin ;__;

ok, I used System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel = "High" and in Output I got

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=14506096) for Binding (hash=28492826)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=14506096): Default mode resolved to TwoWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=14506096): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
```

Comment: did you declare the  FooTypeToStringConverter in the XAML?

Comment: You say you get an exception: which one? paste the exception stacktrace please

Comment: and if you have declared the FootTypeToStringConverter in the xaml, have you used the correct namespace or does the declaration also cause an error (blue underlined)? I think your key (x:Key) in the XAML-Window-Resources isn't "FooTypeToStringConverter".

Comment: could you also post the <Window.Resources>?

Comment: if it's a binding error you can get additionnal information using System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel = "High" in the binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to warning you posted
`System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: ''`

`Path` property is set to null. This means you have to set it. Normally you could do it like this:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding}"
```

which also means same as

```
SelectedItem = "{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

and with converter:

```
SelectedItem = "{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}, Converter="{StaticResource FooTypeToStringConverter}"
```

You can alse use `ObservableCollection<Foo>` instead of `BindableList<Foo>`